# How to CosmoNim (GCC) on Solus Linux? (segfault)

Tags: linux, gcc, nim-lang, compiler-flags, linker-flags

What methods or tools can I use to help figure out the below issue?

I'd like to use [CosmoNim](https://github.com/Yardanico/cosmonim) on Solus Linux. It works on other linux distributions, but produces executables that segfault when built on Solus Linux. CosmoNim works for me on Ubuntu just fine.

- [CosmoNim](https://github.com/Yardanico/cosmonim) is a Nim wrapper to use Cosmopolitan
- [Cosmopolitan](https://github.com/jart/cosmopolitan) is a library and method to produce universal binaries built with GCC
- Nim is a transpiler to C (auto compiling with GCC)
- So CosmoNim should work out of the box on many linux distros (and does indeed work on Ubuntu)
- However, CosmoNim fails to make a functioning executable on Solus (the executable segfaults when run) before doing the `objcopy` to make the full universal executable.
- But! Cosmopolitan (directly using GCC) HelloWorld does work on Solus
- So Nim is either missing some compile or link flags for GCC or it's doing something it shouldn't for this process
- How can I make progress on figuring this out?

Upon using GDB, it reports the main() function for the segfault:
$ gdb hello.elf ...

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000413005 in NimMain ()
121 N_CDECL(void, NimMain)(void) {
```

This is starting at that line 121 in the source file:

```
N_CDECL(void, NimMain)(void) {
        void (*volatile inner)(void);
        PreMain();
        inner = NimMainInner;
        initStackBottomWith((void *)&inner);
        (*inner)();
}

int main(int argc, char** args, char** env) {
        cmdLine = args;
        cmdCount = argc;
        gEnv = env;
        NimMain();
        return nim_program_result;
}
```

$ (gdb) info functions

```
121:    void NimMain(void);
117:    void NimMainInner(void);
137:    void NimMainModule(void);
108:    void PreMain(void);
102:    void PreMainInner(void);
129:    int main(int, char **, char **);
```

Any GDB/compiler utils wizards out there know how to introspect this?

Comment: Some of the "nim.cfg" flags in the CosmoNim package is using a library that is broken in the Solus distro. I played a bit with Solus, and out of the box it gave me three "XXXX.so is missing" (e.g. just opening a terminal).

Comment: @xbello That sounds promising! Do you know which library?